# How do I decode bytes using pyserial in serial communication

Tags: python, serial-port, decode, pyserial

I am a beginner to Python. I have a program that uses pyserial library to communicate with a serial device. The program sends a byte of numbers to the machine and receive number of bytes as reply.

My code is

```
   import serial, string
   port = serial.Serial("COM9", 38400, timeout=10.0)
   serial.PARITY_NONE
   serial.EIGHTBITS
   serial.STOPBITS_ONE
   port.write(bytes([53, 1, 4, 0, 83]))
   print("Write done")
   data = port.read(20)

   data1= data.decode('utf-8')
   print(data1)
```

The ouput is

```
   Write done
   Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Python34\serialcomm.py", line 18, in <module>
   data1= data.decode('utf-8')
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x84 in position 8:                                                                                                               
   invalid start byte
```

The output is supposed to be 
[53,1,4,0,83,53,1,63,83]

If I exclude the decoding, I get

```
  Write done
  b'5\x01\x04\x00S5\x1b\x00\x84S'
```

Comment: Do you know the format you're supposed to be receiving? Because obviously it's not encoded text.

Comment: there is no need of encoding. I have to send as sequence of bytes. I have tool to see if the machine receives it right. The writing part is correct. There is problem only with reading part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `bytes` can be converted to a list of bytes by passing it to the `list` constructor.

```
>>> list(b'123')
[49, 50, 51]
```

Comment: Could you explain how this relates to the problem?

Comment: @EliezerMiron: "The output is supposed to be [53,1,4,0,83,53,1,63,83]"

Comment: So the OP fixed their code by changing print(data1) to print(list(b'data1'))?

Comment: @EliezerMiron: ... No, `list(data)`.

Comment: @EliezerMiron: As the comments on the question say, there is no encoding; it's raw binary data.